# how to connect to snowflake via configure via spring bean in mule3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mule-esb

i am using database connector in mule 3 to connect to snowflake , Can any one suggest how can i connect to snowflake via spring bean config in mule 3

Attaching the screenshot for the reference.

[image: screenshot of the mule3 config]

Comment: try with database URL .You must be having snowflake account URL .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Spring Bean datasource that wraps your database JDBC driver. Usually that is done by using a pool library (don't try your own implementation).

Example using the c3p0 pool library:

```
<spring:beans>
 <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <spring:property name="driverClass" value="${JDBC.driver}"/>
  <spring:property name="jdbcUrl" value="${JDBC.URL}"/>
  <spring:property name="user" value="${JDBC.user}"/>
  <spring:property name="password" value="${JDBC.password}"/>
  <spring:property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
  <spring:property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
  <spring:property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
  <spring:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100"/>
  <spring:property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
  <spring:property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000"/>
 </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<db:generic-config name="dbConfig" dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"  />
```

There are more examples at https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Spring-based-datasources